# Do i have to stop my AWS lightsail instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I just recently discovered AWS new service lightsail. Apparently you're charged by the month which is good, unlike EC2 that is billed by the minute.

However, there seems to be some extra costs, but i'm not able to find what it could be, should i stop my AWS lightsail instances when i'm not using them ?

Comment: Are you able to see the extra cost in https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/aws-cost-explorer/?

Comment: The price is a monthly price for lightsail, but the billing is still hourly pro-rated.

Comment: Can you share screenshot of cost explorer.. Stopping the instance won't have any impact. But you might be using other services like monitoring and data transfer costs can be there too.

Comment: @ChrisWilliams i have lightsail + taxes, no extra cost in the graph (maybe if i don't have any it doesn't show)

Comment: Hmm ok, so you cannot see your extra costs included? Where did you see them? :)

Comment: @ChrisWilliams sorry if my questions was misleading, i've read somewhere in all the documentation i read that there can be extra costs, i wanted to be sure about that since i'm fairly new to AWS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is actually a hypothetical, yes there are a number of additional costs you can end up paying:

- Exceeding your Network allowance will result in an additional charge.
- Exceeding 3 million DNS queries per month.
- Creating a Lightsail Snapshot
- Lightsail Load Balancers.

For a more comprehensive list of potential additional costs, you can take a look at the [Billing and account management](https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/faq/#Billing_and_account_management) section of the Lightsail FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that every static IP Adress is connected to an lightsail instance. This happened to me.